# Copying files using fgets instead of fgetc?

Tags: c, file, fgets, fgetc

I made a code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char * argv[]) // taking files
{
    FILE * fp;
    FILE * fp2;
    int c;
.
. // checking possible problems
.
    while ( (c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF){ // copying one file to another one
        fputc (c, stdout);
        fputc (c, fp2);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fp2);
    fp = NULL;
    fp2 = NULL;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I would ask you, if is it possible to make the same while statement with use of `fgets` function instead of `fgetc`- like:

```
fgets(fp, sizeof(fp), stdin));
```

Comment: Note that since you have `FILE *fp;`, your example `fgets(fp, sizeof(fp), stdin)` would be wholly inappropriate, even though it would compile — C is not a type-safe language at times.  You want `char buffer[4096];` and `fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin)` (or use `fp` instead of `stdin` if you're reading from a file instead).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to use [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) and [`fputs()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fputs.html).
If you're using POSIX systems, you might find [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) better than `fgets()`, but you'd still use `fputs()` with it.  Or you might find [`fread()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fread.html) and [`fwrite()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fwrite.html) appropriate instead.  All of those work on arrays — you get to choose the size, you'd likely be using 4096 bytes as a buffer size.

For example:

```
char buffer[4096];
while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp) != NULL)
{
    fputs(buffer, stdout);
    fputs(buffer, fp2);
}
```

Or:

```
char buffer[4096];
size_t nbytes;
while ((nbytes = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), sizeof(buffer), fp)) > 0)
{
    fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), nbytes, stdout);
    fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), nbytes, fp2);
}
```

<sup>*Warning: uncompiled code.*</sup>

Note that in theory you should test that the `fwrite()` operations worked OK (no short writes).  Production quality code would do that.  You should also check that the `fputs()` operations succeed too.

Note that as [hinted at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53402455/copying-files-using-fgets-instead-of-fgetc/53402575?noredirect=1#comment93680759_53402575) by [user2357112](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2357112/user2357112), the original code will work with arbitrary binary files (containing null bytes `'\0'`) quite happily (though `stdout` may be less happy with it).  Using `fread()` and `fwrite()` will work perfectly with binary files, and the only issue with text files is that they'd ignore newlines and write blocks of text as they're read (which is not usually an actual problem).

Comment: Isn't the `fgets` version also going to have issues with null bytes in the input?

Comment: @user2357112: yes — it is.  If you copy binary data with text functions, you get what you get.  If the copying is for arbitrary files, then `fread()` and `fwrite()` are appropriate because they handle nulls fine.  One problem with `fgets()` is that it does not tell you how many bytes it read, so if you read a line and the newline is missing, it could be because there was a null byte in the input.  But there's no way to know.  The `getline()` function reports how many bytes were read; you could use `fwrite()` to ensure that those bytes are all written.  There are issues with `getline()`, too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to write this program using fgets() and fputs(). We know that fgets() stops reading after encountering a newline or EOF, we can use this property but  in this case, we can't directly use feof() function, else, we can use two file pointers and do something like this:

//after opening the file<*fp> to be read from in "r" mode and the file<*fp1> to be written to in "w" mode.

```
while(1){
if(fgetc(fp)!=EOF) fseek(fp,-1,1);
else break;
fgets(buff,100,fp);
fputs(buff,fp1);}
```